# Why does my code keep returning an error?

Tags: python

I was working on a code for my class when I kept running into a problem. My code was:

```
def MeterToFoot():
  meter = float(input("Enter your distance in meters: "))
print(meter*3.279)
def FootToMeter():
  feet = float(input("Enter distance in feet: "))
  print(feet*0.305)
FootToMeter()
answer = input("Enter yes or no if you would like to calculate meters to feet: ")
if answer == "yes":
  def MeterToFoot():
    if answer == "no":
      def FootToMeter():
```

I was wondering why I kept getting an error, can anyone tell my why?
Also, I know that my code is very messy, but I am just a beginner in python so please bear with me here.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: You seem to not understand the difference between defining a function and calling it. There is no reason to have `def MeterToFoot` more than once. Your indentation also doesn't make sense. Finally -- why not use `else` rather than a second `if`?

Comment: You need to indent your second line.  It's not in the function so `meter` is not defined

Answer (score 2):

1. You only *define* functions with `def`; to *call* them, you just use the funciton name with parentheses. No colon either.
2. Your line `print(meter*3.279)` was not indented, so it was considered out of the scope of `MeterToFoot`, meaning `meter` would not be defined at that point, leading to an error.
3. Your `if` statements at the end needed the indentation fixed, and the second one replaced with `elif`.

Therefore, with these fixes, your code would look like:

```
def MeterToFoot():
  meter = float(input("Enter your distance in meters: "))
  print(meter*3.279)

def FootToMeter():
  feet = float(input("Enter distance in feet: "))
  print(feet*0.305)

FootToMeter()
answer = input("Enter yes or no if you would like to calculate meters to feet: ")
if answer == "yes":
  MeterToFoot()
elif answer == "no":
  FootToMeter()
```

Answer (score 1):

> remove `def` in if condition and Keep minimum 4 space indentation

```
def MeterToFoot():
    meter = float(input('Enter your distance in meters: '))
    print meter * 3.279


def FootToMeter():
    feet = float(input('Enter distance in feet: '))
    print feet * 0.305


FootToMeter()
answer = \
    input('Enter yes or no if you would like to calculate meters to feet: '
          )

if answer == 'yes':
    MeterToFoot()

if answer == 'no':
    FootToMeter()
```